# A duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

See this question on Stack Overflow:

[What is the difference between != and =! in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825840/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-java)

It is a **duplicate of**:

[What's this =! operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029174/whats-this-operator)

which is **a duplicate of**:

[What does the "=!" operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228060/what-does-the-operator-do)

1. Why such duplicate-chains? Shouldn't it be impossible that a duplicate question can be marked as duplicate of another question that is already a duplicate?
2. What is the currently longest duplicates chain on Stack Overflow?
3. Is it actually possible to create a duplicate-loop?

==> Now you can mark this question as a duplicate of another duplicated question.

Comment: 1.  Unicoins
2.  Unicoins
3.  Pretty sure it's... Unicoins.

Comment: i heard that if you say it three times then a unicoin will appear!!!

Comment: It's duplicates all the way down!

Comment: It's a pyramid scheme of duplicates.

Comment: When you see this, you should mark the last one as a duplicate of the first one in the chain. By closing the loop we form a question sink that can accept all duplicates everywhere. These are referred to as möbius dupes, and are the preferred duplicate tail format.

Comment: So you are saying sometimes a duplicate != a duplicate and that while duplicate == duplicate we should be looking for if a duplicate != duplicate from anywhere in the previous tree?

Comment: finally it got closed as duplicate! Luckily not as a chained duplicate :-P

Comment: By the way, your title is off by a duplicate.

Comment: I seem to be seeing this more often. Example: [this question today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26554424/1250301). Is this actually desirable? The first dupe does have good answer, but so does the dupe of the dupe. Should these be merged at some point?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 2. What is the currently longest duplicates chain on Stack Overflow?

Infinite, see next part.

> 3. Is it actually possible to create a duplicate-loop?

Yes. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211710/238586).

Okay, to be serious: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6633197/2846923) question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6633190/2846923) question which is a duplicate of the first question. There's a bunch of other cases of this linked to in this query I made: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/179727/duplicate-chains.

Comment: I was working on something similar and it was clear when I kept hitting recursion limits (32,767) that there are probably some very lengthy chains. Some posts appear [thousands of times on their own](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/179737) - though at the high end those are most likely all duplicate targets.

Comment: a duplicate of itself... I would say that condition is always true. Will have to flag a lot of questions as duplicates :-P

Comment: I am dissatisfied with the answer to the question... actually 3 questions, more precisely the "why" of it. These chains only cause confusion and do not help anyone. They should be merged. And if the questions are different enough to warrant different answers, then they are not duplicates.

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to look a little closer to see how this happened in this specific case.

Your first question, asked over two years ago, was marked as a duplicate by a moderator on January 12 at 2:08 AM UTC:

[image]

Your second question, at that time, was not a duplicate yet. It was subsequently - over 12 hours later - closed as a duplicate by five community members, who likely didn't know about the other closure:

[image]

There are a couple of things here worth mentioning.

1. It should perhaps be more obvious that a question has been identified as the target for closure of another question - if that happened in the past. In this case, obviously, it was not "another question that is **already** a duplicate" (emphasis mine).
2. I don't feel the software should prevent these chains. Especially when questions have been around for varying amounts of time, have collected their own different answers, etc. I don't feel that all questions closed as a duplicate should necessarily point to the same master question unless it really is a very good canonical question (and that's something the community should decide, not the system). I bring this up a lot but in my field (SQL Server) we often have questions that have good answers for older versions, but for newer versions there are better, newer answers on different questions. I would rather close the new question as a duplicate of the newer, better question with its better answer, even knowing that I can't control that question from itself later being closed as a duplicate of the older question. It is still good to have the user follow through that better post, with a chance they may read it (and any comments about why it's better on the modern version), than to skip it altogether because "chaining is bad."